# Problem with Cmake with lapack API not found

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, lapack

When trying to build a file and compile it when I did `cmake ..` I've got the message below:

```
-- Configuring main project: VideoNLBayes
-- Setting CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH as /home/me/local/ for local libraries
-- A library with BLAS API found.
-- Could NOT find LAPACK (missing:  LAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindLAPACKE.cmake:107 (message):
  Required LAPACKE API not found.  Please specify library location.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/me/Bureau/vnlb-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/me/Bureau/vnlb-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I used these commands for installing lapack and blas:

```
sudo apt-get instal liblapack-dev
sudo apt-get instal libcblas-dev
```

and I also tried with installing

```
sudo apt-get instal liblatlas-dev
```

But I don't understand why it keep telling me this error.

I tried also to install with another kind like downloading it and making link.
I'm new in Ubuntu and I don't know exactly how to make path and change paths and something like that.

Comment: You can specify library location with link_directories() in the CMakeLists.txt file. This will tell CMake where to look. They may be installed correctly but CMake cannot find them.